# Did Ripley age between Alien and Aliens?

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-1979, aliens-1986, cryogenics

When Ripley was in Cryo-sleep between *Alien* and *Aliens* did she age at all? The person in Cryo is still alive, reduced heart rate etc, but given that you wouldn't normally be 'asleep' for so long any small ageing would be unnoticeable surely one as long as 57 years would show some ageing on Ripley? (Looking 7 years older due to filming dates doesn't count)

Comment: The dupe makes it clear that cryosleep isn't totally suspended animation. The inhabitants of the cryotubes have their vitals *slowed* but not stopped.

Comment: @Valorum I don't see an answer to my question although the points are noted. Not being frozen and showing vital signs indicates a reduced body function (keeping the brain alive etc) would mean that you would still age even though at a very very slow rate?

Comment: There are endless quotes from the novel/s (which I've alluded to) that would apply, for example; "*Every so often, though, a dark and vile memory would rise to the fore, like sewage seeping up beneath a city street. Temporarily it would overwhelm her rest. Then she would moan within the capsule. Her heartbeat would increase. The computer that watched over her like an electronic angel would note the accelerated activity and respond by lowering her body temperature another degree while increasing the flow of stabilizing drugs to her system."*, etc etc. Clearly the sleeper isn't frozen solid.

Comment: So did Ripley show signs of ageing??

Comment: @Valorum I don't believe my question to be a dupe as I have never mentioned being frozen solid and my Q is about ageing while in Cryo sleep. How do I challenge this duplicate tag?

Comment: You have several choices. You can add an edit to explain why you don't think it's a dupe, you can add a comment explaining why you don't think it's a dupe or you can post a meta question asking for the community to reopen the question

Comment: Could you explain, for example, how the duplicate doesn't answer the question of whether cryosleeper ages at a slower rate?

Comment: @Valorum Can you explain how it does? The dupe answer talks about suspended animation etc but doesn't talk about ageing or am I missing a line somewhere?

Comment: *"The novelisation makes it clear that the cryotube doesn't create a perfect stasis (a la Star Trek) but functions as a suspended animation device, **slowing the user's vital signs but not stopping them**. Entering in an unwell state might delay your death but it certainly wouldn't stop it."*

Comment: So the answer to my question (not a dupe) is 'due to the unusually long Cryo-sleep Ripley may have showed signs of ageing but it is not mentioned anywhere in canon'?

Comment: I don't think it requires **any** stretch of the imagination to go from "*slowing the user's vital signs but not stopping them*" to "*the user of the cryotube ages more slowly, but still ages"*

Comment: Really? Can't you open the question back up and let other people decide that?

Comment: Why would I need to? They can simply read the dupe and the answer is waiting there for them. That's literally the point of dupe closure. If the question covers the same ground, we don't need them to be worded identically, especially if an upvoted answer on another question gives a strong answer to both questions.

Comment: The question I asked doesn't appear in the 'dupe' and neither does the answer. This seems to be opinion!

Comment: It helps if you extend the title of the dupe to its logical conclusion; (*Why don't they freeze Kane* ***[to completely halt his vital signs]***? Then the dupeness is a bit more evident